# Flutter how to create textfield with two icons on right, same as in image?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create TextField widget same as image, on x I need to clear input, on search icon I need to call some method that is not important here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4U3G.png)

This is code for now without x icon.

```
TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                userTappedSearch(value);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "search",
                  suffixIcon: 
                    Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 20),
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            color: SBColor.navyBlue,
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                              topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            )),
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                            color: SBColor.white,
                            onPressed: () {})),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                  ))),
            ),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a TextField and a Container inside a Row to achieve that:

```
TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

final border = OutlineInputBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(left: Radius.circular(5))
);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  hintText: 'Search',
                  border: border,
                  errorBorder: border,
                  disabledBorder: border,
                  focusedBorder: border,
                  focusedErrorBorder: border,
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _textController.clear();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue[800],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(10))
              ),
              child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,), onPressed: (){}),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Result:

[image: Search Widget]

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use the build-in properties of the `TextField`. You easily can use as many icons as you want.

For example:

```
prefixIcon: IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
    print('search button pressed');
  },
  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
),
suffixIcon: Container(
  width: 100,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print('add button pressed');
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print('mic button pressed');
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

As a result, you get `TextField` (or `TextFormField`) like this

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I should have checked the signature but for some reason I thought suffixIcon and prefixIcon took Icons and not Widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Icon Button` In a `Row()` and then just have two `Icon Button`s as children, You can customize the background color of each Icon to create the search bar in the image (Transparent on the X)

Comment: If I do that typed text will not be visible

Comment: Then change the suffix icon to the X and wrap the Textfield in a row with the search button as a second child (Or have both buttons as children)